# Change the precision of torch.sigmoid?

Tags: pytorch, torch, sigmoid

I want my sigmoid to never print a solid 1 or 0, but to actually print the exact value

i tried using

```
torch.set_printoptions(precision=20)
```

but it didn't work. here's a sample output of the sigmoid function :

```
before sigmoid : tensor([[21.2955703735]])
after sigmoid : tensor([[1.]])
```

but i don't want it to print 1, i want it to print the exact number, how can i force this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [difference between 1 and the exact value of sigmoid(21.2955703735)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+sigmoid%2821.2955703735%29) is on the order of 5e-10, which is significantly less than [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) for `float32` (which is about 1.19e-7). Therefore 1.0 is the best approximation that can be achieved with the default precision. You can cast your tensor to a `float64` (AKA double precision) tensor to get a more precise estimate.

```py
torch.set_printoptions(precision=20)
x = torch.tensor([21.2955703735])
result = torch.sigmoid(x.to(dtype=torch.float64))
print(result)
```

which results in

```
tensor([0.99999999943577644324], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Keep in mind that even with 64-bit floating point computation this is only accurate to about 6 digits past the last 9 (and will be even less precise for larger sigmoid inputs). A better way to represent numbers very close to one is to  directly compute the difference between 1 and the value. In this case `1 - sigmoid(x)` which is equivalent to `1 / (1 + exp(x))` or `sigmoid(-x)`. For example,

```py
x = torch.tensor([21.2955703735])
delta = torch.sigmoid(-x.to(dtype=torch.float64))
print(f'sigmoid({x.item()}) = 1 - {delta.item()}')
```

results in

```
sigmoid(21.295570373535156) = 1 - 5.642236648842976e-10
```

and is a more accurate representation of your desired result (though still not exact).